# How do I show that $\frac a{1 - a^2} + \frac b{1 - b^2} + \frac c{1 - c^2} \ge \frac {3 \sqrt 3}2$

Tags: inequality

For $0 \lt a, b, c \lt 1$, if $ab + bc + ca = 1$, show that $$\frac a{1 - a^2} + \frac b{1 - b^2} + \frac c{1 - c^2} \ge \frac {3 \sqrt 3}2.$$

I want to use trigonometric substitution:

For the angles $A, B, C$ of any acute triangle, $$\tan A + \tan B + \tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C,$$ $$\frac 1{\tan A \tan B} + \frac 1{\tan B \tan C} + \frac 1{\tan C \tan A} = 1.$$

Also, $\tan A, \tan B, \tan C \gt 0$. So I substitute $a, b, c$ for $\frac 1{\tan A}, \frac 1{\tan B}, \frac 1{\tan C}$ respectively. Then the inequality in question becomes $$\frac {\tan A}{1 - \tan^2 A} + \frac {\tan B}{1 - \tan^2 B} + \frac {\tan C}{1 - \tan^2 C} \le -\frac {3 \sqrt 3}2.$$

Here $A, B, C \not = \frac {\pi}4$ since $a, b, c \not = 1$.

By the trigonometric identity $\tan 2A = \frac {2 \tan A}{1 - \tan^2 A}$, we have

$$\tan 2A + \tan 2B + \tan 2C \le -3 \sqrt 3,$$

where $0 \lt A, B, C \lt \frac {\pi}2$, $A, B, C \not = \frac {\pi}4$, and $A + B + C = \pi$.

How do I proceed?

Edit: The restriction $a, b, c \lt 1$ was added after the question had received some answers, thanks to Michael Rozenberg, who pointed out this mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**:  Lets use $a = \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)$. You can define $b, c$ similarly, then your inequality becomes: $\tan(A) + \tan(B) + \tan(C) \geq 3\sqrt{3}$, with $0 < A,B,C < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $A+B+C = \pi$. And this inequality is standard result of convexity of $\tan(x)$ over $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still another question: Can this inequality be proved from the mean inequality? Because this exercise actually appears at the end of a chapter introducing the AM-GM bound.

Comment: I think you can.

Comment: But how, then? My primary intuition was to use the AM-GM bound but I just cannot see how. Can you give me a hint or something?

Comment: Sure. I am working on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously wrong! Try $a=1.01$ and $b=c=\sqrt{2.0201}-1.01$.

Comment: Since you are giving an answer that disagrees with both the Question and the two other posted Answers, you might help your Readers follow your objection more easily by spelling out the computation.

Comment: @hardmath $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{1-a^2}-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}=-51.8567...$ for my counterexample.

Comment: Okay, my arithmetic (I made a Google Sheet) gives $-49.25865721$ for the expression that is supposed to be bounded below, but the sum $ab+bc+ca$ does come out to be $1$.  So I agree with the basic conclusion.

Comment: @hardmath I think your are wrong with $-49.25...$

Comment: @hardmath I wrote $\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}$ before and if you got another number so it's your mistake  and it's not my mistake.

Comment: Put it this way: Since I got $\frac{a}{1-a^2} + \frac{b}{1-b^2} + \frac{c}{1-c^2} = −49.25865721$, this is the expression that is supposed to be bounded below by $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. If we now subtract $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we get $−49.25865721 - 2.59807621135 = -51.8567334214$.  It matches your figure, just as you wrote the subtraction.

Comment: Note that there was a comment, now removed, by someone else who thought that $ab + bc + ca = 1$ was not true with your example.  The point I was making there is that it is true.

Comment: Maybe I missed some restrictions to $a, b, c$. And since you've provided your counterexample, the proofs provided ought to be wrong. Can you point out where the wrong step is and how can I refine my question?

Comment: Maybe adding $a, b, c \lt 1$ will do? Okay, I just noticed that in the trigonometric substitution it is assumed that $a, b, c \lt 1$, since $a = \tan \frac A2 \lt \tan \frac {\pi}4 = 1$, where $0 \lt A \lt \frac {\pi}2$. I'll edit it. Thank you @MichaelRozenberg. But actually I think this should posted as a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: @YuxiaoXie:  That is the restriction I suspect is needed (so $a,b,c \in (0,1)$).  But I would defend Michael's posting this as an Answer, because it does settle your original framing of the Question (I have no problem with your adjusting the problem to take account of Michael's observation).

Answer (score 1):

We can prove $S=\sum\tan A=\prod\tan A$

Using [AM GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality) if $\tan A,\tan B,\tan C\ge0,$ $$\dfrac{\sum\tan A}3\ge\sqrt[3]{\prod\tan A}$$

$$\iff\dfrac S3\ge\sqrt[3]S\implies\left(\dfrac S3\right)^3\ge S\iff S^2\ge27$$ as $S\ne0$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to prove it with AM-GM, I will give one proof using AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz. 
Note that the given condition implies that $a+b+c\geq\sqrt 3$. In addition, I will use the following two inequalities. $$(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\leq a^3+b^3+c^3+6abc$$ and $$abc\leq\big(\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\big)^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$ Now, 
$$\sum\limits_{a,b,c} \dfrac{a}{1-a^2}\sum\limits_{a,b,c} a(1-a^2)\geq (a+b+c)^2.$$ But $\sum\limits_{a,b,c} a(1-a^2) = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-a^3-b^3-c^3\leq abc\leq \dfrac{6}{3\sqrt 3}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 3}$. These two combined together implies that $$\sum\limits_{a,b,c} \dfrac{a}{1-a^2}\geq\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 3}}\geq\dfrac{3 \sqrt 3}{2}.$$
 The first inequality is called Schur's inequality.

**EDIT.**

Actually an even easier solution is obtained by using $$\dfrac{a}{1-a^2}+\dfrac{9}{4}a(1-a^2)\geq 3a,$$ by AM-GM. Thus, $\sum\limits_{a,b,c} \dfrac{a}{1-a^2}\geq\dfrac{3}{4}\sum\limits_{a,b,c} a+\dfrac{9}{4}\sum\limits_{a,b,c} a^3\geq\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot\sqrt 3 + \dfrac{9}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} = \dfrac{3 \sqrt 3}{2}$. That $a+b+c\geq\sqrt 3$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ are trivial from the given condition.